# Span inside div doesn't style correctly

Tags: css, html

I want to use span inside div

div is used to put a red horizontal line

```
<div style="background-color:red;">
</div>
```

**span is used inside div** to put elements to right

```
<div style="background-color:red;">
<span style="float:right;">
ABC
</span>
</div>
```

But **the horizontal line do not get red color, only ABC is shown in right, infact there is no effect of div style like width:900px..**....why?

Comment: Add overflow:auto to your div's style definition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
<div style="background-color:red; text-align:right;">ABC</div>
```

Otherwise, you need to add `overflow:auto` to your div's style definition if you do want to leverage the `<span>` as in your original example.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Add `overflow:auto` to the div:

```
<div style="background-color:red;overflow:auto;">
<span style="float:right;">
ABC
</span>
</div>​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TtKGy/)**

Floating the inner span causes the div to essentially collapse, and adding the overflow rule allows it to regain the span.

Answer (score 2):

The float is not giving your div any height. You need to follow it up with a `clear`. Try this:

```
<div style="background-color:red;">
  <span style="float:right;">
    ABC
  </span>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this may work, adding extra DOM elements to achieve what is otherwise a proper use of CSS is generally considered a hack.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add the property `overflow:hidden`; in your DIV.
Below I mentioned the Code:

```
<div style="background-color:red; text-align:right; overflow:hidden;"> ABC </div>
```